# Google App Engine losing CSS on deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

When I deploy my app to Google App engine the CSS is no longer found.  The app is fine in the localhost.  I'm not sure why this is exactly.  Does the app engine change the file structure?  I get the following error in the log:

```
2012-10-26 14:04:37.727 Static file referenced by handler not found:
stylesheets/main.css
```

Here's my app.yaml

```
application: vipermonkeyswhofly
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: vipermonkeyswhofly.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: 2.6
```

My index.html has this url:

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="/stylesheets/main.css" />   </head
> ```

I appreciate any help that you can provide.  I'm sure it's something obvious that I'm missing but it's eluded me up to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the folder and file are also lower case on your filesystem. (/stylesheets/main.css)
If you're on Windows then it seems not to be case sensitive but the production environment is.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing of note is that the main.css is only created in the section titled "Using Static Files" which comes after "Using JSPs".  So, if your like me and deploy after each section, you'll see this error until you create the main.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting that in your `app.yaml` file, if you have the following mappings:

```
# static directories #
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

your HTML file needs to reference them like this (note the leading / in the file path):

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```